# Get data from file and move through pipes

Tags: c, linux, unix, io, ipc

#### Disclaimer: this is for an assignment. I am not asking for explicit code. I am only asking for help understanding the concepts so that I may learn the material without copying what someone else has done.

My assignment is to take some data from a text file, parse out the words, sort them alphabetically, delete the duplicates, and output them to a new text file. This is to be done using three processes, using pipes for IPC. This is the first time I've worked with pipes or any IPC for that matter, so if I come across a bit uninitiated, please understand.

So I've forked the main function into three processes: input/parent, sort(child), and output(grandchild). I've created an IO stream within the parent process and need to pipe it to the sort proc. I've created that pipe and closed the unused ends (`stdin` for input, `stdout` for sort.)

My issue is this: I don't know how to move the data from the IO buffer into the pipe (at stdout). I feel like it should use `fputs`, where a parsed word list would be passed into `stdout` one word at a time.

Below is what I have created thus far for the input proc. File IO is not my strong suit, so if there are errors there, please let me know and I'll do what I can to fix them. Thank you for your help!

```
} else {                            /* This is the input/parent process */

    printf("This is the input process\n");

    close(input_to_sortFD[0]);      /*  
                                     * Closes the parent-side read-end of
                                     * the pipe 
                                     */

    pipeStream = fdopen(input_to_sortFD[1], "w"); /* 
                                                   * Buffer that feeds into
                                                   * write-end of pipe
                                                   */


    ioFileFD = fopen(ioFile, "r");
    if (ioFileFD == NULL) {
        perror("Fatal error: failed to open requested file");
        exit(-1);
    }

    int i = 0;

    while (fscanf(ioFileFD, "%s", wordList) != EOF) {
        fputs(wordList[i], stdout);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are working way too hard.  You should not be writing anything in C: you can solve this problem with 20 keystrokes, plus the name of the files.  (Although the 20 key solution only uses 2 processes.)

Comment: I miscounted: if you count the carriage return, it's 21 keystrokes.  It looks like your assignment is to write this in C, so apologies if this is a spoiler, but I'm worried that if I don't add the actual solution here, 3 years from now I will read the comment and wonder what I was thinking of.  So here it is: <infile tr \  \\n|sort -u>outfile but I will not highlight it to prevent you from accidentally seeing what you said you do not want to see!

Comment: Error messages that say "requested file" instead of giving the actual filename are one of the most irritating things in the universe!  Use `perror( ioFile )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is:

> I don't know how to move the data from the IO buffer into the pipe (at stdout).

From what I gather, you are over-thinking the problem. If you know how to read from a `FILE *` and write to a `FILE *`, then there is nothing special about a pipe.

I would structure the program like this:

- parent process

  - opens input and output files, creates pipe
  - launches child process "wordify"
  - launches child process "sortunique"
  - waits for children to finish
- wordify process

  - reads input and writes words
- sortunique process

  - reads words, sorts unique occurrences, and outputs the resulting list

You can prototype the "wordify" and "sortunique" processes using `sed` and `sort` respectively. The prototype below defines words to be contiguous occurrences of alphabetic characters.

```
void wordify (FILE *infile, FILE *outfile)
{
    int r;
    make_stdio(infile, outfile);
    r = execlp("sed", "sed", "-e",
               "s/[^a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*/ /g;s/^ *//;s/ *$//;/^$/d;s/ /\\n/g",
               (char *)0);
    assert(r == 0);
}

void sortunique (FILE *infile, FILE *outfile)
{
    int r;
    make_stdio(infile, outfile);
    r = execlp("sort", "sort", "-u", (char *)0);
    assert(r == 0);
}
```

Since the prototype uses `execlp()`, the `infile` needs to be mapped to `stdin` and the `outfile` needs to be mapped to `stdout`. This is accomplished with `dup2()`, but I implement a wrapper function `fdup2()` that deals with `FILE *`.

```
FILE * fdup2 (FILE *oldstream, FILE *newstream)
{
    if (newstream) {
        if (fileno(oldstream) != fileno(newstream)) {
            if (dup2(fileno(oldstream), fileno(newstream)) < 0) return 0;
            fclose(oldstream);
        }
        return newstream;
    }
    return oldstream;
}

void make_stdio (FILE *infile, FILE *outfile)
{
    FILE *x = fdup2(infile, stdin);
    FILE *y = fdup2(outfile, stdout);
    assert(x && y);
}
```

The processes are launched with `fork()` as expected.

```
void launch (void (*func)(FILE *, FILE *), FILE *infile, FILE *outfile)
{
    assert(infile && outfile);
    switch (fork()) {
    case -1: perror("fork");
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    case 0:  func(infile, outfile);
             exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    default: fclose(infile);
             fclose(outfile);
    }
}
```

Now, the main program just has to open the input and output file, create the pipe, launch the processes, and wait for them to finish. The only trick is that the pipe has to be used so that the write end of it is the output for `wordify`, and the read end of it is the input for `sortunique`.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *infile;
    FILE *outfile;
    int pipefds[2];
    int r;

    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "need input and output filenames\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((infile = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == 0) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((outfile = fopen(argv[2], "w")) == 0) {
        perror(argv[2]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    r = pipe(pipefds);
    assert(r == 0);

    launch(wordify, infile, fdopen(pipefds[1], "w"));
    launch(sortunique, fdopen(pipefds[0], "r"), outfile);
    while (waitpid(-1, 0, 0) == 0) {}

    return 0;
}
```

Notice, there are a total of 3 processes participating. If you must launch 3, and have 4 processes participating, I would consider splitting `sortunique` into `sort` and `unique`.

```
    r = pipe(pipefds1);
    assert(r == 0);
    r = pipe(pipefds2);
    assert(r == 0);

    launch(wordify, infile, fdopen(pipefds1[1], "w"));
    /* sort: behaves like "sort" command with no arguments */
    launch(sort, fdopen(pipefds1[0], "r"), fdopen(pipefds2[1], "w"));
    /* unique: behaves like "uniq" command with no arguments */
    launch(unique, fdopen(pipefds2[0], "r"), outfile);
    while (waitpid(-1, 0, 0) == 0) {}
```

Once you have the problem broken down to these components, then working on implementing a particular component is just a standard reading input and writing output exercise. The pipe issue is abstracted away as file streams arranged in the proper order, and components just read and write. You can even remove the `make_stdio()` code, and read from the `infile` and write to the `outfile`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, pipe communication is done with read() and write() calls. But I see that you're promoting the int file descriptor to a FILE* so that you can use fscanf and friends.

If you're using fscanf() for reading, you can use fprintf() for writing.